# Python: Remove duplicates in a list pass into new list (Recursion)

Tags: python, list, recursion, duplicates, erase

I am trying to learn recursion. I am trying to take a list as a parameter and return a new list in which the values that were in the old list appear only once in the new list. 
I have been going at this for hours but keep getting stuck.

Comment: Post removed all code. No longer useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (old_list[0] not in new_list):
```

Notice that new_list will always be empty at this point, so this condition will always be true and all elements will be added to the new list.

Your code is one little tweak away from functioning correctly. Instead of checking if the item is in the new_list, I think you should be checking if it's *in the rest of the old list*:

```
if (old_list[0] not in old_list[1:]):
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was in the second if-statement:

```
def bag_to_set(old_list):
    new_list = []
    if old_list == []:
        new_list = []
    else:
        if (old_list[0] not in old_list[1:]):
            new_list = [old_list[0]] + bag_to_set(old_list[1:])
        else:
            new_list = bag_to_set(old_list[1:])
    return new_list
```

Looks like this fixes it, by replacing new_list with old_list[1:] in the conditional

Comment: You did his homework for him without really explain what he did wrong, or why it was wrong.

Comment: No I just realized thanks to the post above and this one. My if statement always evaluated to true. Because I was checking old_list[0] with new_list which at the start is empty. So now it checks if old_list[0] is in old_list[1:]. If old_list[0] not in old_list[1:] execute the block and do the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Silly question: Why have the second if after the else? I think it might be a little smoother to say:

```
if old_list == []:
  new_list == []
elif old_list[0] not in old_list[1:]:
   new_list = [old_list[0]] + bag_to_set(old_list[1:])
else: 
   new_list = [old_list[0]] + bag_to_set(old_list[1:])
```

This avoids 1 level of nesting. A minor point, but I thought it might be worth tossing out there...